# jQuery append last item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a dynamic input box list with the help of [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ykXa).

I want to, when I press the "add" button, create the new entry before the first input box.

I've tried some jQuery methods like `.before(), .prepend(), .prependTo()` but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<div id="type-elements" class="controls">
<div class="form-row entry">
    <div class="form-inline mb-4">
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-link text-success btn-add mr-1" href=""><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="Materia" required name="fields[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <select class="custom-select" required multiple size="3">
            <option disabled>Seleziona una o più classi</option>
            <option>2DM</option>
            <option>2AM</option>
            <option>2DM</option>
            <option>2AM</option>
        </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger')
        .html('<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>');
}).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
{
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was looking into your work. I used `prependTo`

```
newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).prependTo(controlForm);
```

And it works!!

Issue is with your classes:

```
controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
```

It is prepending new entry but the css being used when clone with newEntry

Just change not(:last) to not(:first)

```
controlForm.find('.entry:not(:first) .btn-add')
```

And you will understand what is going on